# How to set value of circular slider in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using https://github.com/princejwesley/circular-slider in my project which is based on Ionic Framework(Cordova) and angularJS.

My target is to have an circular slider with 3 steps: Low,Medium, High. So when 0 is selected it should show Low, for 1 'Medium' and 2 should be high. I am unable to call setValue function in slide. so that everytime user slides corresponding value is to be displayed.

```
var intensity = $('#intensity').CircularSlider({
    //I used ui.find() method but its not working
    shape: "Half Circle",
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    value: 0,
    touch: true,
    setValue: function(value) {
        console.log('inside set');
        value = value * 10;
        return value;
    },
    slide: function(ui, value) {
        console.log('inside slide');
        console.log(value + "ui" + ui);
        ui.find('.jcs-value ').setValue(0); //I used this method to set value on ui
    },
});
```

I tried `ui.find('.jcs-value').setValue`, `ui.setValue` or `intensity.setValue` in the slide function but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your requirement by using jQuery [**roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin, since this is very flexible and easy to customize.

For more details about the roundSlider, check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Please check the sample demo for your requirement [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/7/).

**Screenshot of the output:**

[image: circular half slider - jquery plugin]